# ASP.NET MVC action not found on first request after AppDomain restart, when using [HttpGet]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have a public ASP.NET MVC action that uses [HttpGet], like so:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult List(OrganizationFilterModel p_model) {
    ...
}
```

If a user requests a page without a valid user session, we redirect them to the login page. The login system redirects them to the originally requested URL after logging them in.

On this page, under certain circumstances, the redirect from the login system to the original URL results in an exception being thrown:

*A public action method "List" was not found on controller "MyApp.Controllers.OrganizationController".* However, **if I simply re-request the page, it displays successfully then and for all subsequent requests.**

Conditions and other notes:

1. The user has a valid FormsAuth ticket. [*Meaning, they were recently logged in*]
2. The user's session is gone, due to expiration or an AppDomain reset.
3. Removing the `[HttpGet]` fixes the problem. [*Even though the failed request WAS a GET*]

Under these conditions, the existence of the `[HttpGet]` filter prevents MVC from finding the action, but only on the first request. All subsequent requests work fine.

Fiddler shows the following pattern:

- GET to /Organization/List --> *returns 302 to login page*
- GET for /Account/Login
- POST to /Account/Login [*user logs in, then gets redirected*]
- GET for /Organization/List --> *throws error*
- GET for /Organization/List --> *if I repeat the request, it works fine*

**Summary:** the `[HttpGet]` filter is preventing the action from being located, but only on the first request and despite the fact that it *is* a GET request.

What's going on?

**Update:**
To add some additional information:

1. Using MVC 4
2. We use FormsAuth but do NOT use the `[Authorize]` attribute. We have custom code in `OnActionExecuting` that forces a login if the request is authenticated, but doesn't have a valid session. (*We really just use FormsAuth for some of the static convenience methods and configuration settings*)
3. The issue DOES NOT occur if FormsAuth causes the redirect to the login page. The issue DOES occur if our custom code causes the redirect.
4. Removing FormsAuth altogether fixes the issue as well.

Since removing FormsAuth fixes the issue, and we've wanted to do that for awhile, I'm ceasing troubleshooting. I'd really love to know if this is a defect in FormsAuth + MVC [or FormsAuth + Routing], or if I've done something stupid.

Comment: I could not reproduce the error using MVC4 and "internet application" template, an action with [authorize] that takes a viewmodel, and a GET request that triggers authentication and redirect.
Perhaps there are more details?
What version of MVC, what is the code that authorizes and redirects, and are there any custom filters or HttpHandlers that might affect this?